# Reading global variables

Tags: r, global-variables

All I can find is how to write to global variables, but not how to read them.

Example of incorrect code:

```
v = 0;

test <- function(v) {
  v ->> global_v;
  v <<- global_v + v;
}

test(1);
print(v);
```

This yields `2` because `v ->> global_v` treats `v` as the local variable `v` which is equal to 1. What can I replace that line with for `global_v` to get the 0 from the global `v`?

I'm asking of course about solutions different to "use different variable names".

Comment: There's probably a better way to do this but could you do something like `with(globalenv(), v) ->> global_v` to replace the first line of your function? Use of the `<<-` operator in that line seems a bit unnecessary though.

Comment: This indeed works, thank you. The `->>` was just my attempt to read the global variable, it's indeed unnecessary when you refer to it with `with(globalenv(), v)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `with(globalenv(), v)` to evaluate `v` in the global environment rather than the function. `with` constructs an environment from its first argument, and evaluates the subsequent arguments in that environment. `globalenv()` returns the global environment. Putting those together, your function would become this:

```
test <- function(v) {
  v <<- with(globalenv(), v) + v;
}
```